# How can I use the Lucida Grande font in Windows?

Tags: windows, fonts, notepad++, eclipse

I'm a Windows user but I want to use the Lucida Grande font in Notepad++ and Eclipse IDE.

I didn't find that font listed for Notepad++ when I tried to change the font in the style configurator.

Does anyone know any tweaks to make this happen?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason you can't find Lucida Grande among your installed fonts is that it doesn't come with Windows. If you want to use it, you have several options:

- <strike>Buy the font, as noted in [RedGrittyBrick's answer](https://superuser.com/a/486347/108226)</strike> The font doesn't seem to be available for purchase.
- The font was also [supposedly available with Safari for Windows](http://www.personal.psu.edu/ejp10/blogs/gotunicode/2008/02/lucida-grande-coming-to-window.html), but Apple has since discontinued that. An archived version of Safari 3 along with instructions to extract the font is available [here](http://log.samuelkelly.net/post/81626746).
- You can use Lucida Sans Unicode instead, which does come with Windows and is [almost identical to Lucida Grande](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida_Grande#Similarity_to_Lucida_Sans).
- A quick search online for "lucida grande" provides a number of places where you can just download it. I won't list them since I'm not sure about their legality, plus it's not like they're hard to find.

Answer (score 4):

You can buy [various Lucida fonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/lucida/fonts/) but exclusive rights to Lucida Grande are owned by Apple. Lucida Grande is copyright by the font designers Bigelow and Holmes but is [not available for sale](http://www.identifont.com/show?63U).